# Google Drive Reports API for files count

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to use Google Drive Reports API /admin/reports/v1/usage/users/all/dates

Is there any report parameter we can use to get total number of files owned by a user?

For example "accounts:drive_used_quota_in_mb" gives total used quota. Similar to this is there any parameter for total number of files?

Comment: This would be really helpful. In admin app, I can see some users with a single file created, but accounts:drive_used_quota_in_mb still shows 0.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no parameter regarding the total number of files count using Reports API based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/usage-ref-appendix-a/users-drive). You could probably use [Admin SDK Reports Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports) using Google Apps Script.